# Sprite not being affected by physics

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, physics

I want a `SKSpriteNode` to keep moving through the screen and bounce with the edges forever. So I set the physics of the edges:

```
    let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
    borderBody.friction = 0
    self.physicsBody = borderBody
    physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)
```

And then the physics of the sprite:

```
    ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
    ball.size = CGSizeMake(30, 30)
    ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
    ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
    ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
    ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
    ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0
    ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))

    self.addChild(ball)
```

The problem is that the sprite is not being affected in anyway by the physics and stays on the center of the screen. What did I do wrong?

Comment: Try upping the impulse a bit and see if that helps.

Comment: you have no gravity,  what force makes this ball move,  try setting an initial velocity for your ball

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you need to add the ball to your scene before you apply the impulse to it.

```
import SpriteKit

class GameScene: SKScene {
    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {

        let borderBody = SKPhysicsBody(edgeLoopFromRect: self.frame)
        borderBody.friction = 0
        self.physicsBody = borderBody
        physicsWorld.gravity = CGVectorMake(0, 0)

        let ball = SKSpriteNode(color: SKColor.redColor(), size: CGSizeMake(30, 30))
        ball.position = CGPointMake(CGRectGetMidX(self.frame), CGRectGetMidY(self.frame))
        ball.physicsBody = SKPhysicsBody(circleOfRadius: ball.size.width/2)
        ball.physicsBody?.allowsRotation = false
        ball.physicsBody?.restitution = 1.0
        ball.physicsBody?.linearDamping = 0.0
        ball.physicsBody?.friction = 0.0

        self.addChild(ball)
        ball.physicsBody?.applyImpulse(CGVectorMake(10, -10))
    }
}
```